# How to avoid scaling issues in WebView in CardScrollView in Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I added 2 `WebView`s inside `CardScrollView`. Like this:

```
    CardScrollView
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X---Web---X----Web--X
X--View---X---View--X
X-----1---X------2--X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I read, that it's probably [discouraged](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView), but nontheless, someone has to try it :)

I experienced scaling issues inside page, when I started swiping back and forward.
Each webpage's content was scaled down on X axis 2 times.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my own question.

Issue got solved, when I added to my `WebView` in layout file:

```
android:layerType="software"
```